# Oracle SQL - query children table to find matching parent

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table vehicle_master
vehicle_id | vin
1          | 1234
2          | 5678
3          | 9123

Table vehicle_inventory

vehicle_id | key       | value
-----------|-----------|------
1          | Make      | Honda       
1          | Model     | Civic        
1          | Year      | 2004        
2          | Make      | Toyota
2          | Model     | Corolla
2          | Year      | 2005        
2          | color     | white   (every row is optnl: key/row may or may not exist in db)
3          | Make      | Honda       
3          | Model     | Civic        
3          | Year      | 2004     
3          | color     | blue
```

I am trying to find a vehicle with given make, model and color. Color restriction can be specified in input query but it may not be available in DB. If a car in DB has no color specified, it should be matched even if a color is specified in query

The SQL I have so far:

```
select * from vehicle_master vm where 1=1
and exists(
    select 1 from vehicle_inventory vi
    where vi.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id
          and (vi.key=':make' and vi.value=':makeValue')
)
and exists(
    select 1 from vehicle_inventory vi
    where vi.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id
          and (vi.key=':model' and vi.value=':modelValue')
)
and exists(
    select 1 from vehicle_inventory vi
    where vi.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id
          and (vi.key=':color' and vi.value=':colorValue')
)
```

For inputs Make:Toyota,Model:Corolla,Color:white, I get the result 2|5678 as expected.

If I input Make:Honda,Model:Civic,Color:red, I get no match or results because color key for the Honda doesn't exist in DB. I want the color restriction ignored in this instance because there is no db entry. I want the color to be considered in the search only if there is a key and value present for the color

How do I make the key/value pair match conditionally if the row with the key exists, and ignore the restriction if the key/value row doesn't exist in DB?

Edit: every key is optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use aggregation here.  For example, to search for a white Honda Civic we could try:

```
SELECT
    vm.vehicle_id,
    vm.vin
FROM vehicle_inventory vi
INNER JOIN vehicle_master vm
    ON vi.vehicle_id = vm.vehicle_id
GROUP BY vm.vehicle_id, vm.vin
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN vi.key = 'Make'  AND vi.value = 'Honda' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN vi.key = 'Model' AND vi.value = 'Civic' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    (SUM(CASE WHEN vi.key = 'color' AND vi.value = 'white' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR
     SUM(CASE WHEN vi.key = 'color' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0);
```

The final two terms of the `HAVING` clause say, in plain English, find vehicles having the color white *or* vehicles which have no color appearing at all.

Comment: The results are same as my query. This query with above data returns no results because its looking for a row that has key that says 'Color' The data for Honda doesn't have a 'Color' attribute, just clarifying that in addition to the value being null, the key is also "null"

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, changing SUM(CASE WHEN key = 'color' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) to SUM(CASE WHEN key = 'color' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) seems to work. Is it possible to also get vin from a single query using a join, or is a second query necessary to get the vin because when group by is used, it doesnt seem to allow more columns in select?

Comment: Your change to my having clause makes no sense to me.  But I have updated my query to bring in the VIN number from the other table.

Comment: If I add the vin and the join clause, I get an error ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression. I changed "GROUP BY vm.vehicle_id" to "GROUP BY vm.vehicle_id,vm.vin"

Comment: @Matrix If `vehicle_id` is a primary key in the `vehicle_master` table then that error should not have happened.  In any case, I can't see your data, so maybe I assumed too much.  Happy to help you find a solution.

Comment: @Tim you can't have expressions in the SELECT that do not appear in the GROUP BY clause. By keeping your original group by clause, you could just fix that using a group function: SELECT vm.vehicle_id, MAX(vm.vin)

Comment: @AlexZen Oh yes you can.  If you `GROUP BY` a column you may select any other column which is _functionally dependent_ on that column.  This is the ANSI standard, but perhaps Oracle does not fully implement it.

Comment: @AlexZen Oracle is really old school, I didn't know this.  Most other databases would support my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using subqueries and aggregations like:

```
select b.vehicle_id, b.vin
from
    (select * from vehicle_master vm where
    exists(
        select 1 from vehicle_inventory vi
        where vi.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id
              and (vi.key='Make' and vi.value=':makeValue')
    )
    union all
    select * from vehicle_master vm where
    exists(
        select 1 from vehicle_inventory vi
        where vi.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id
              and (vi.key='Model' and vi.value=':modelValue')
    )
    union all
    select * from vehicle_master vm where
    exists(
        select 1 from vehicle_inventory vi
        where vi.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id
              and (vi.key='Color' and vi.value=':colorValue')
    )) b
group by b.vehicle_id, b.vin 
having count(*)=3;
```

You would need just 3 variables, the keys are constants.

Answer (score 1):

By not changing the structure of your query, you could just change your third subquery to a constraint NOT EXISTS. You could check if it does exist a record in vehicle_inventory with color different from the one you're looking for:

```
and NOT exists(
    select 1 from vehicle_inventory vi
    where vi.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id
    and (vi.key=':color' and vi.value != ':colorValue')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could say that if the color exists for the make then check it, otherwise don't check it.

```
SELECT  vm.*
  FROM  vehicle_master    vm
       ,vehicle_inventory mk
       ,vehicle_inventory mo
 WHERE  mk.vehicle_id = vm.vehicle_id
   AND  mk.key = 'Make'
   AND  mk.value = ':makeValue'
   AND  mo.vehicle_id = vm.vehicle_id
   AND  mo.key = 'Model'
   AND  mo.value = ':modelValue'
   AND  (EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM vehicle_inventory co
                  WHERE vm.vehicle_id = co.vehicle_id
                    AND co.key = 'color'
                    AND co.value = ':colorValue') OR
     NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM vehicle_inventory co
                  WHERE vm.vehicle_id = co.vehicle_id
                    AND co.key = 'color') )
```